# jax-rs: How to implement custom parameter validation?

Tags: java, validation, jax-rs, bean-validation

I want to create custom annotation (e.g. `@ValidAddress`) which will validate object (using custom logic not related to JSR303) and throws an exception in case of invalid value:

```
    public Response registerAddress(@ValidAddress Address address)
```

It's pretty easy to implement with `javax.validation.Constraint` and `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` ([sample](http://www.makeinjava.com/validation-of-rest-parameters-using-jersey-framework-part-2/)) but it has strange limits:

1. Annotation should have `message` / `groups` / `payload` params
2. isValid can't throw custom exception

The question:

How to add custom annotation which will execute `myFunction($param)` on every request where `$param` is annotated bean deserialized from body

Comment: are you using Spring?

Comment: nope, we use dropwizard

Comment: I don't think the limitations you are mentioning are strange. If you want to use Bean Validation (that's where the javax.validation namespace is coming from), you need to adhere to the requirements of the standard. Only this way it can be assured that any constraint built-in as well as custom behaves in a consistent way within the framework. If you have different requirements you will indeed need to find another solution.